# printing matrix square shape c#

Tags: c#, matrix

I have an 8*8 matrix and here is my code:

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        const int matrix_rows = 8;
        const int matrix_columns = 8;
        double[,] matrix = new double[matrix_rows, matrix_columns];
        for (int i = 0 ; i < matrix_rows ; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < matrix_columns; j++)
            {

                    Console.WriteLine(matrix[i, j]+ "\t");

            }
            Console.WriteLine("\n");
         }
        Console.ReadKey();
```

I want it to be printed square shape but it prints one "0" in each line. what should I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You write a new line each time. Do `Console.Write()` instead of `Console.WriteLine()`

Answer (score 3):

It's because you're using `Console.WriteLine` each time in your inner loop - so every value is printed on a new line.

Also, if you replace `Console.WriteLine("\n");` with `Console.WriteLine(string.Empty);` you won't get an extra blank line between each line.

Try this for your loop and see what you think of the output:

```
        for (int i = 0; i < matrix_rows; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < matrix_columns; j++)
            {
                Console.Write(matrix[i, j] + "\t");
            }
            Console.WriteLine(string.Empty);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Because your array is empty!

Look, you create it

```
double[,] matrix = new double[matrix_rows, matrix_columns];
```

and then print it. The default value for `double` is `0`

Comment: I don't think the issue is that `0` is the value that is getting printed, but rather that each value is on a new line where the OP wants each value printed within the `matrix_columns` iteration to be on the same line.
But your point is entirely valid.

Comment: Ok, thank you @MattJones. First I think that the problem with `0` now I see that  OP means `WriteLine`. I just won't edit the answer because you've already asnwered. I've already upvoted you